# Virial theorem for atoms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, atomic-physics, virial-theorem

How [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) applies to atoms? For example we can use it to calculate the average kinetic energy for an electron in the hydrogen atom. But Virial theorem states that:
$$\langle{K_{sys}}\rangle=\frac{-\langle{V_{sys}}\rangle}{2}$$
So it clearly relates the kinetic and potential energy of the system. What allows us to use it for the individual particles of the system?

Comment: Why can’t we use it for individual particles?

Answer (score 1):

In the Schrodinger equation for a hydrogen atom in the Born-Oppenheimer approximation the nucleus is “clamped,” and thus has no degrees of freedom. Its only purpose is to fix the coordinate system and to give the electrostatic interaction experienced by the electron. Thus, the electron is the only particle that has any degrees of freedom in the system. Hence, the virial theorem applies to the individual electron particle in the hydrogen atom. In many-particle systems with non-trivial degrees of freedom (e.g. the helium atom) there is no such ability to exploit the virial theorem for each particle. It only applies to the overall many-body wavefunction. Instead, it only tells you about the overall kinetic energy and potential gradient (forces) for the system as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

Virial theorem relates the average kinetic energy of a system to its average potential energy. Since quantum mechanically we can define kinetic energy operator $\hat{p}^2/2m$ and the potential energy operator $V(\hat r)$ we can always find the expectation value of these operators for any state $|\psi\rangle$. The state could be pertaining to a single particle system or a multiparticle system.

Comment: How can potential energy be given to a single particle when it is a property of the system not just of one particle (unlike kinetic energy)?

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas Kinetic energy is relative to a reference system (because the velocity that enters into its definition is relative). In this case we are calculating it in the rest system of the nucleus.